# two wizards loading at the same time in swt

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have two wizards ProjectWizard and ModifyEditWizard. I am adding both in the same page like below

```
      projectPage = new ProjectPage(objSelected);
      addPage(projectPage);

modifyeditpage=new ModifyEditPage(objSelected);
    addPage(modifyeditpage);
```

also using :

public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage currentPage) {

```
 currentPage.setPreviousPage(projectPage);

      if(currentPage!=null && currentPage instanceof ProjectPage ){


         modifyeditpage.setProjectIdValue(projectPage.getProjectIdValue()); 

         return modifyeditpage;
      }

    return null;
}
```

The Problem I'm facing is the two page gets loaded at the same time when  this wizard. I want to take input from first wizard and according to that populate data in next wizard.

Comment: This is very unclear. You talk about 'ProjectWizard' and 'ModifyEditWizard' but then show us what looks like code for a single wizard using 'ProjectPage' and 'ModifyEditPage' (so pages not wizards). Also what does 'two pages get loaded at the same time' mean?

Comment: The ProjectWizard is the main page where i have included two wizard "ProjectPage" and "ModifyEditPage" where i need when ProjectPage gets loaded then from input taken from this Page The ModifyEditPage should be loaded.

Comment: So what is not working with your current code? Overriding `getNextPage` like this is fairly standard.